# Script configure unattended upgrades with fcron

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

How can I update and upgrade the system every 24h of machine's up time. I don't know where fcron saves the crontab for `USER`

```
myCrontab="/etc/$USER/path/to/fcrontab"
    if [ ! -f $myCrontab.bak ]; then
        cp $myCrontab $myCrontab.bak
        echo "@ 24h sudo apt-get -y --force-yes update  &&  sudo apt-get -y --force-yes upgrade"
    fi
```

Comment: It should be here `/var/spool/cron/crontab` but note files are added via`sudo crontab -u username`

Comment: so I do `sudo crontab -u $USER` and then `echo "string" | sudo tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontab/$USER`. The problem is I don't see any file in that directory after doing the first command.

Comment: No no no! One moment

Comment: See here: http://fcron.free.fr/doc/en/fcrontab.1.html